# Read the Pre-login ssh banner from PHP

Tags: php, ssh, stream

I'm trying to use the libssh2-php library functions to connect to an ssh server from PHP. That's all great, but I can't figure out how to read the pre-login banner in PHP. The Pre-login banner is text displayed before SSH prompts for a login, and as far as I can tell I can't get a stream from the connection object.

So given this code, is there any way to do a read prior to logging in?

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
      // log in at server1.example.com on port 22 
if(!($con = ssh2_connect("server1.example.com", 22))){
  echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {

 //####### Would really like to get a stream right here to read pre-login banner

// try to authenticate with username root, password secretpassword
if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "root", "secretpassword")) {
    echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
} else {
    // allright, we're in!
    echo "okay: logged in...\n";

    // execute a command
    if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "ls -al" ))) {
        echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
    } else {
        // collect returning data from command
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $data = "";
        while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
            $data .= $buf;
        }
        fclose($stream);
    }
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). The banner should be obtainable by doing `$ssh->getLastError()` (returns a string) or `$ssh->getErrors()` (returns an array of strings).

Quoting the source of it:

```
// see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4252#section-5.4; only called when the encryption has been activated and when we haven't already logged in
if (($this->bitmap & NET_SSH2_MASK_CONSTRUCTOR) && !($this->bitmap & NET_SSH2_MASK_LOGIN) && ord($payload[0]) == NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_BANNER) {
    $this->_string_shift($payload, 1);
    extract(unpack('Nlength', $this->_string_shift($payload, 4)));
    $this->errors[] = 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_BANNER: ' . utf8_decode($this->_string_shift($payload, $length));
    $payload = $this->_get_binary_packet();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I spent most of last night reading the RFC and the source code for that library. Its a great library, with one problem. Opensshd 4.3 requires the authentication method to be "none" for the login banner to show up. This is actually a bug in sshd, that was fixed, but I'm stuck with 4.3. My next task is to see if I can make this library change authentication methods from password to none easily. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Update (after discussion):

Currently I see no way to do this in php except from implementing it on your own. Sending a feature request to developers of the ssh2 extension might be best way to start.

---

Original (stupid) answer:
The login banner will appear after the login

Comment: Yessir, the login banner will appear after the login. I'm interested in getting the pre-login banner. As you can see in this example, sshd has the option to display some text prior to authentication. Where this is enabled, I'd like to read it. Come to think of it, I also wonder how to capture the actual text from the login prompt if I wanted to. http://d.pr/i/89iY

Comment: Ok, I see. Will investigate your problem. Sounds interesting! :)

Comment: Thanks for spending time on this. I did contact the author on sourceforge to request this feature be added. After more research I found a pure PHP implementation of the SSH2 protocol at this SourceForge project: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/
It appears to offer lower level access.

Comment: Damn! I should had told you this. I know this lib. Thought you are not interested in it. However, now you know yourself! It should work well. But I just didn't some little feature testing with it once.